# Unique constraint excluding NULLs in UDT field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2012 and I have the following User Defined Table Type

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[IdentifierCodeTable] AS TABLE(
    [Id] [dbo].[Identifier] NULL,
    [Code] [dbo].[Code] NULL
)
```

I am trying to enforce that `Id` must be `Unique` except for `NULL` values.
I have the following code and it is working fine for `NON NULL` values but when I try to insert 2 `NULL` values it does not allow me to do it.

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[IdentifierCodeTable] AS TABLE(
    [Id] [dbo].[Identifier] NULL,
    [Code] [dbo].[Code] NULL,
    UNIQUE(Id)
)
```

Is there any way to exclude the `NULL` values from that UNIQUE Constraint like I can do in the regular indexes with the filter?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to accomplish this using the unique constraint instead of using a unique index?

Comment: Nope, I can use a `unique` index over the `UDT` field too. The problem is I was browsing the web and I couldn't find a way to create an custom index over a field in an `UDT` (I just can create a `PK` or use the `UNIQUE` constraint)

Comment: I tried with `CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UK_IdentifierCodeTable] ON [dbo].[IdentifierCodeTable](Id)` and SQL Server raises the exception `Cannot find the object "dbo.IdentifierCodeTable" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.`. I think this is because it is not a Table/View.

Comment: Ok.  My brain decided that that was a table not a UDT.  Out of curiosity, what are you trying to accomplish with a table UDT?  This seems like you might be making things way harder than they need to be.

Comment: I am using the table UDT to call a stored procedure from other stored procedure with a table as a parameter.

Comment: Could you just use a temp table / table variable / sub-select to do that instead?

Comment: That was my previous solution but I am using the stored procedure in many places and I prefer to move the table structure to an UDT Table to avoid to rewrite all the structure every time I have to use it.

Comment: While I believe this may not be the best option, you could try a [CLR UDT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131120.aspx).  With that you may be able to do what you want.  I don't believe what you want is possible with a TSQL defined UDT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is all I need to know (It is SQL Server 2008 but i think it applies to SQL Server 2012 either).

*A nonclustered index cannot be created on a user-defined table type unless the index is the result of creating a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint on the user-defined table type. (SQL Server enforces any UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY constraint by using an index.)*

Source: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522526%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: Yep, same in 2012 too. 2014 allows non unique indexes but not filtered indexes as you need.